# facebook like button like impression differ with different query string

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I had page with listing of atlest 25 deals. each deal will have a like button (fb:like) the url for each deal will be "www.xyz/deals/dealtitle("nice-dress-best-offer")?userId=xyz" like this

In the above link "dealtitle" will differ for each deal and userid will differ for different users. If a like impression was happened for the above link for one userId, it is not counted for some other userId. If user is logedin to my website the url will be with "?userId=xyz" query string other wise "www.xyz/deals/dealtitle("nice-dress-best-offer")"

If the 2 like impression was given on both links it has to show 2 people liked it, count has to show 2. But it is not doing like that, it is taking like two different urls. My website contains urlrewrited links. That deal title will not appear like a querystring but the userid will be...

Can any one tell me how to eliminate userid for like button impression..

Thanks in advance.

can any one tell me how

Comment: Facebook like buttons with query string values work sometimes, but not always. A handful will work, but something as simple as changing a number value in one of your querystring vars will stop the button from working, which is insane! I've lost hours trying to work around this bug. No success. It's definately random.

Answer (score 3):

So what you are saying:

- You have a product **X**
- The product can have different pages based on the user browsing the product
- You need all the `LIKE`s on the different pages to that product to have the same count

If this is the case, I suppose you need to use the Open Graph Meta Tags on all the pages:

- `og:title` - The title of the entity.
- `og:type` - The type of entity. You must select a type from the list of Open Graph types.
- `og:image` - The URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.
- `og:url` - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.
- `og:site_name` - A human-readable name for your site, e.g., "IMDb".
- `fb:admins` or `fb:app_id` - A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID.

Where the `og:url` should point to a ***generic*** page for that product (like a public profile that is the same for all users)!